# How many citric cycles are (can) working at the same time in one mitochondria?

Tags: cell-biology

Does one mitochondria has a limit of how many acetyl-CoA it allowes within his inner membrane to produce NADHs? And if, lets say 100 acetyl-CoA are in a mitochondria are they simultaniously running through their citric acid cycle or has the mitochondria also a limit for the amount of running citric cycles at the same time?

Comment: Seems the amount can vary, because the mitochondria's volume could vary.